# Why does the stethoscope node not work inside groups in Sverchok?

Tags: sverchok

Sverchok: Does anybody know why the stethoscope node doesn't show values inside a node group? Or does some workaround exist? (yeah, of course i could have the nodes "outside" the group...i know ;)

[image]

Comment: I think it's the same issue for which we didn't have ctrl + shift + click with node wrangler in the shader editor, a node group can be instantatied any number of times in any node tree, and I don't know if there is a way to know exactly when its logic is ran, and for which instance the inspection node should show its values. I don't know the in and outs of all this though, so it's pure speculation :)

Comment: My note is also blurry :) and doesnt have to relate ... it just happens from time to time to me - since nodes are closed into group, node tree provides some  disfunctions.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i asked this question on github and they answered:

you found an unfortunate corner case for monads ( a very early and primitive implementation of Group Nodes for sverchok); namely those two nodes:

-frame info node
-all nodes that draw openGL-type instructions (either to nodeview (stethoscope..) or to 3dview..(viewer draw, doesn't create a Blender mesh in realtime it only draws a mesh)